# Cannot read property ‘children’ of undefined ionic

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I am getting an error while trying to read a json. I am using asp.net web api.

My code looks like this:

```
export class ProdutoListaPage  {

  public produto: Array<string>;
  private url: string = "http://localhost:50907/api/consulta/BuscaProduto";  

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http:Http) {

   this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.produto = data.data.children;
      }); 

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProdutoListaPage');
  }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @MitchWheat,I started studying a little while ago about Ionic, my knowledge is not great, if you can help I thank you,

Comment: @MitchWheat , I did not find in the research on this problem

Comment: @itasouza, are you sure that you are handling the response (data) in the right way? Can you try to print a log of  `data`?

Comment: @DarwinMedina, I tested this example with another json, everything worked fine
Https://www.reddit.com/new.json, only on my web.api does not work

Comment: <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let prod of produto">
      {{prod.nomeproduto}} - R$ {{prod.preco}} 
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

Comment: @itasouza yep in this example (https://www.reddit.com/new.json) works fine because it exists a `data.data.children`in the response, if your api response is this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPrmr.png the correct way to assign the `produto` array is this : `this.produto = data;`

Comment: @DarwinMedina, Friend, you got the solution to my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your api response is this : [image: i.stack.imgur.com/LPrmr.png] the correct way to assign the produto array is this : `this.produto = data;`